Is it possible to run multiple wayland sessions at the same time?
Sometimes I try to contribute patches to wayland compositors. In order to test them, I usually go to some tty (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F2) and start it there. However, I noticed that this often breaks my original session:

When I trigger gnome-keyring to unlock, the password prompt is displayed on the new display.

I have a custom dbus service that needs to get the PID of the caller. This fails with the following message:
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name ':1.1771': no such name (3)


In the past I also noticed that waybar will act as a StatusNotifierHost, replacing the one from the original session. This seems to be fixed now.

I think there is more, but I can't remember right now.


Most things seem to go back to normal when I execute this:
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY WAYLAND_DISPLAY

I do understand that this is complex. Some services should be run for the user, others for the session, and others should be shared for all sessions of the same user on the same seat. But as far as I know, there is only a dbus session bus. I was not able to find much documentation on this.
My question is: Is it even intended to be possible to have multiple wayland sessions for the same user? In that case I would be happy about some pointers to related documentation so I can start fixing some of the services that are currently broken.

With systemd, your D-Bus "session bus" is usually turned into a user-wide bus (at a fixed socket address) and both your Wayland sessions end up using the same one. That is, apps on the new session will be connecting to the "user bus" and talking to waybar on the original display, and so on.
For testing, you should ignore the "user bus" and manually start a separate session bus:
$ dbus-run-session ./thecompositor

In the past it was usually done using dbus-launch --exit-with-session, but dbus-run-session may be a little more reliable (in cleaning up when the session exits).
This works with traditional session environments, where the session manager starts everything directly (or via D-Bus activation); it will not work with environments that expect to start things through systemd specifically (e.g. gnome-session in its "systemd" mode), as it is no longer possible to have more than one copy of 'systemd --user' per user. (Related to that, if you try to use 'systemctl --user' in such an environment, it will actually connect to systemd through a private socket instead of session bus.)

Is there any documentation on why systemd is behaving that way and how users are expected to use this single user bus?

The "official" statement usually repeated on the mailing list is that systemd deliberately doesn't support more than one graphical session per user, because of various session components that are single-instance (e.g. GNOME's dconf using a 'single DB writer' that breaks down if you have two session buses as it allows for two writers and possible corruption, or GVFS using a single fixed per-user FUSE mountpoint, etc).

(Plus, I sort of remember there was a wish to get away from tons of per-session environment variables – randomized /tmp socket path in DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, another randomized /path in PULSE_SERVER, etc. – replacing them with simpler and predictable /run/user/UID/bus, /run/user/UID/pulse, etc. I remember there being a large patchset for things like libX11 that would make them default to XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/foo; not all of it got accepted, but many things did convert to that model. Now in theory this would allow multiple XDG_RUNTIME_DIR per user, but in practice, unfortunately.)

As for the systemd --user service manager specifically, I don't think there is any documentation (one day it simply was switched from being something you'd start from CLI to something that is automatically started as user@UID.service, once per UID), but the fact that it uses cgroups for service management (just like the system-wide one) might have contributed to it; all of [last comment] makes me think they very much did not wish for each 'systemd --user' to generate a randomized cgroup path every time, but to use a clean fixed one that could be mechanically derived from just the UID.

Answering my own Question / adding more background information.
There are multiple aspects to this.

logind has a concept of sessions. loginctl lock-session will for example lock all of the user's sessions.
Wayland has a separate socket for each display, so applications that use the wayland protocol can exist separately for each session.
There is $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, but in systems that use systemd that bus is actually the same for all sessions of the user. Accoring to https://systemd.io/DESKTOP_ENVIRONMENTS/, "systemd only supports running one graphical session per user at a time".
Many session services use dbus, so they share the user bus. Desktop environments also embraced systemd for session management. See this GUADEC talk from 2019 for a discussion of pros and cons.
The tray in waybar is one example of such a session service. In that specific case, the spec allows multiple StatusNotifierHosts to coexist, but there can only be one StatusNotifierWatcher.
Some session services need to be able to access the display (e.g. gnome-keyring to show a password prompt or pipewire to capture the screen). For this, they need to know which display is currently active. You can provide that information using dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DISPLAY WAYLAND_DISPLAY

So I think the proper way to do this is:

Make sure to update the dbus environment when you switch sessions
Services that absolutely must be run for each session (e.g. waybar, swayidle/swaylock) should not be started as systemd user services.

Here is a quick script to automatically update the dbus environment when the session changes. I think this is overkill, but maybe someone finds this useful:
import os
import subprocess

from gi.repository import Gio
from gi.repository import GLib

seat = os.environ['XDG_SEAT']
session = os.environ['XDG_SESSION_ID']


def on_change(conn, sender, path, iface, signal, params, user_data=None):
    if params[1].get('ActiveSession', [None])[0] == session:
        subprocess.run([
            'dbus-update-activation-environment',
            '--systemd',
            'DISPLAY',
            'WAYLAND_DISPLAY',
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM)
    conn.signal_subscribe(
        'org.freedesktop.login1',
        'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',
        'PropertiesChanged',
        f'/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/{seat}',
        None,
        0,
        on_change,
        None
    )
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    loop.run()

